# WPF Application not working on Windows Server OS's(VM)

Tags: wpf, windows, server, runtime-error

I can not run my application on windows server operation systems that runs on VM.
Error details are below;

```
Problem signature:


 Problem Event Name:    CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: EAdaptorManager.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 5956146d
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.6.1649.1
  Problem Signature 06: 58f97efe
  Problem Signature 07: 4168
  Problem Signature 08: 0
  Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.400.8
  Locale ID:    1055
  Additional Information 1: 5861
  Additional Information 2: 5861822e1919d7c014bbb064c64908b2
  Additional Information 3: 5f25
  Additional Information 4: 5f2531ae070278f893fa99352dadd49e
```

Answer (score 0):

we would need more details to help you.  The exception is FileNotFoundException so this is a missing file.

Not neccessarily a file you are manually loading, but may be a DLL from a component used by your program.  Are you sure you included all dependencies when you transported your program to your server?

Comment: It works well another windows server os. Just not working on our customer's server :(